# what pattern to use for notifcation of updates?

Tags: angularjs, broadcast

I am trying to design a angularcrud application where I can notify other users if an object has been updated. I have been reading a little bit about broadcasting and watchers. Just no idea where to place the code that handles all this? Should I implement a singleton messageservice that is injected in all my modules/controllers that handles this? Anyone experience with this?

Comment: I'm just learning Angular myself, so this may not be the way to handle it, but can't you store "global" data in a service? Ref this link: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-services.html

Comment: I respectfully disagree with this statement.  Services are singletons used to store instances of data.  I've been doing angular for a while and it appears to be socially acceptable in the ng-community to do this.  Plus it comes in handy with things like notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I built a custom notification module.  I made a module that has a directive and a singleton service like you said.

I'll share it with you:
https://github.com/breck421/angular-notifications/blob/master/NotificationModule.js

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks,

Jordan

Comment: hi Jordan , I am looking for a way of communicating between one or more sessions by passing on messages not necesarryly using a visual message, thnks